# Automount flash drive lags

Tags: 13.04, usb-drive, automount

I have 1GB flash drive and on Windows or other Linux machines it works fine. But when i push flash drive in my USB port on Ubuntu 13.04 3.8.0-29-generic, there is 1-3 minutes delay before automounting. Please help me to figure out why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to kernel 3.8.0-30 solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with a usb2 pny 32gb ntfs formatted pendrive. Dropping back to kernel 3.8.0-27 solves the issue. I am running xubuntu 13.04 64 bit.

Seems to be fine with my usb2 kingston ntfs pendrives so maybe brand chipset related bug / issue with this kernel ??

Can someone confirm if this is a new bug ?